Combining multiple files by year (column in data) into one line and add file name as first column in Perl or Python
I have over 3000 files that need to be combined based on specific attributes in the files. For example, each file is named by its ID (Eg. 101567AD_Mly.txt).These IDs correspond to latitude and longitude values that I will concatenate to the file after. I need to add a leading column in each output file with the ID. I would then like to merge lines in the input files so that the output looks like IDENTIFICATION, YEAR, JANUARY MONTH CODE (1), JANUARY PRECIPITATION, FEBRUARY MONTH CODE (2), FEBRUARY PRECIPITATION, MARCH MONTH CODE (3), MARCH PRECIPITATION......
Currently, the files are separating each month into a new line like the example below where it is currently structured as YEAR, MONTH, UNKNOWN VALUE, PRECIPITATION AMOUNT.I would like to combine the 3000+ files based on the ID for each, which is their filename. Ideally, I would have a file for each year of data (1979,1980, 1981, etc) so that all files with those years of data (eg. 1981) would all be in one file with each line representing a different ID. The filenames describe the identification of where this data came from so I would like it as the leading column in each file.
Here is an example of what the files look like:
YEAR, MONTH, REMOVE THIRD COLUMN, PRECIPITATION 
1980 1 0 112.106
1980 2 0 131.909
1980 3 0 58.842
1980 4 0 42.075
1980 5 0 45.268
1980 6 0 126.168
1980 7 0 30.159
1980 8 0 32.168
1980 9 0 39.48
1980 10 0 46.117
1980 11 0 234.089
1980 12 0 180.227
1981 1 0 62.795
1981 2 0 131.817
1981 3 0 73.429
1981 4 0 77.282
1981 5 0 54.224
1981 6 0 81.217
1981 7 0 18.469
1981 8 0 12.695
1981 9 0 83.4
1981 10 0 130.957
1981 11 0 151.07
1981 12 0 190.582
1982 1 0 210.604
1982 2 0 143.732
1982 3 0 26.124
1982 4 0 45.952
1982 5 0 10.38
1982 6 0 33.602
1982 7 0 42.218
1982 8 0 9.541
1982 9 0 39.356
1982 10 0 87.037

The third column can just be removed.
Any help to combine all these using perl or python would be great. Either a one-liner or script. I am using linux to do this.
The guy who used to do this work and based everything around Perl has retired leaving a lot of gaps in the knowledge transfer. I am struggling to piece some of it together.
The output format should look like:
IDENTIFICATION, YEAR, MONTH CODE, PRECIPITATION FOR THAT MONTH
ADB103884_Mly, 1989, 1, 123.56, 2, 56.23, 3, 58.9, 4, -99.99, 5, 6.9, 6, 48.2, 7, 89,1, 8, 85.3, 9, 98.1, 10, 190.2, 11, 283.9, 12, -99.99

The output file can be called the year_mly.txt
If there are missing values for a specific month, it should be given a value of -99.99. This way, every ID has a value for each month of the specified year.

HI Kaitlin! This is a tiny bit too broad, because we're not a free code-writing service. We love to help, though! Can you explain what you've tried and where you're stuck? To me, this looks like if you want it in Python, you are probably somewhat familiar in Python and could easily read in the lines from a file, split each line across the space characters, and then just write the elements you need into the right file. Have you tried something similar?

(1) Rather than showing 34 lines of input data that are (AFAICT) identical, features-wise, it would be better to show a sufficient representative sample of input data and show what you want to get as output.   (1a) In particular, what do you want the 2024 file to look like (given that you, presumably, have data for some, but not all, months of the current year)?  In general, what do you want to happen if some month(s) are missing?   (2) What do you mean by “each initial file”?   (3) Do any of your data values include space(s)?  … (Cont’d)

(Cont’d) … (4) Are you saying that you have 3000+ files of approximately 537 lines each (one per month, January 1980 through the present), and you want to end up with 45 files (one per year) of 3000+ lines each?  Please clarify.

Yes, I have 3000+ files that I need to pare down to around 45 files (one per year of data). Each file would include the following columns in each line. IDENTIFICATION, YEAR, JANUARY MONTH CODE (1), JANUARY PRECIPITATION, FEBRUARY MONTH CODE (2), FEBRUARY PRECIPITATION, MARCH MONTH CODE (3), MARCH PRECIPITATION......

Please edit your question and include everything people asked for in the comments. We need to see representative input, and the output you want from that example input. We also need to see the file names so we don't waste your time or ours giving solutions that don't work.

Please see https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting

So you want all of these years from the input (1980, 1981, 1982) to become 1989 in the output? Please show us the output you want from the input you give.

I created fake intput data like this:
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
for my $id ('aaa' .. 'eod') {
    open my $out, '>', "file.$id" or die "file.$id: $!";
    for my $year (1979 .. 2023) {
        for my $month (1 .. 12) {
            printf {$out} "%d %d 0 %f\n", $year, $month, rand() / (1 + rand);
        }
    }
}

And then processed them by the following Perl script:
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

my %by_year;

for my $file (glob 'file.???') {
    my $id = substr $file, -3;
    open my $in, '<', $file or die "$file: $!";
    while (my $line = <$in>) {
        my ($year, $month, undef, $precipitation) = split ' ', $line;
        die "Duplicate $id $year $month" if exists $by_year{$year}{$id}{$month};
        $by_year{$year}{$id}{$month} = $precipitation;
    }
}

for my $year (keys %by_year) {
    open my $out, '>', "$year.out" or die "$year.out: $!";
    for my $id (sort keys %{ $by_year{$year} }) {
        say {$out} join ' ', $id, map { $_, $by_year{$year}{$id}{$_} } 1 .. 12;
    }
}

You didn't show how exactly your files are named, so you'll have to adjust the line that does the glob as well as the one that extracts the id (using substr here).

The input files are all named like 101C0ME_A.txt with varying letter and number combinations.

I edited the original question to help answer some questions asked. Thank you for your help!!!

You can try tweaking my solution to your real data. Ask a new question if you get stuck.
